# Using an elastic IP with an AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

It sounds like I cannot use an elastic ip with AWS Application Load Balancer.

I currently own a domain through GoDaddy and the DNS server points to the load balancer via the CNAME. However, if the load balancer dies and gets recreated, its url changes and I then have to change the CNAME and wait for the change to propagate.

There must be a solution around this - what is it?

It looks like the solution might be to use two load balancers - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/, but this seems really excessive - I have a small application right now.

Comment: You can have two load balancers and dns for failover record https://in.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Server-Failover-setup/td-p/99088 however , aws charge for elb even if it's running idle but it'll cost less then mentioned in above link,  however, I would suggest using cloudfront with origin failover feature, cloudfront cname is static so you don't need to change anything (even in DNS record like failover record etc )

Comment: This question has been answered at Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/q/947633/153161 AWS Global Accelerator allows attaching static anycast addresses to one or more ALBs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to have a fixed static-IP for a LB is to use a Network Load Balancer.

As stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html)

```
Support for static IP addresses for the load balancer. You can also assign one Elastic IP address per subnet enabled for the load balancer.
```

Answer (score 0):

An Elastic Load Balancer retains its DNS name as long as you don't replace it manually. If you still want to have a temporary, low-cost solution to this problem, you can consider the following approach:

Assuming the application is deployed in a private subnet, I would proxy the traffic through an EC2 instance until your primary DNS changes propagate.

- Launch a small EC2 instance and attach an Elastic IP to it (consider your bandwidth requirements to determine which size).
- Configure a proxy (nginx) to forward traffic to your application.
- Configure active-passive DNS failover using ELB DNS name and EIP.